# Photo retrieval from hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro

My Macbook was smashed and subsequently ruined. I was able to save the hard drive and am wondering if it is possible to retrieve the photos that were on it. I don't care about anything else that is on it.

Comment: Does the harddrive look intact otherwise? If it is you can buy a hardrive - usb enclosure and connect it to any other PC

Answer (score 2):

Unless the hard drive was damaged, you should still be able to get your things off. You'll need:

1. A set of adapter cables (similar to the USB enclosure @crasic recommends), which will run you [~$10 on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001OORMVQ) or hopefully similar at CompUSA or Fryes or whatever. The advantage of the cables over the enclosure is that the cables are cheaper, and you don't need the permanence the enclosure provides.
2. Another Mac, preferably, or a Windows PC running something like [Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows-free/).

Once you have these, plug the SATA-to-USB cable into the appropriate slots, then do the power. Try not to move the disk while it's in use, as this could damage the moving parts. Get what you need, and MAKE SURE TO EJECT THE DISK before unplugging it.

(Despite the ominous warning, it is reasonably hard to mess up a good drive unless you're super careless. Don't worry too hard, just don't do anything stupid.)